# Can a Pentecostal marry a Jehovah witness

Tags: marriage, jehovahs-witnesses, pentecostalism, 2-corinthians

My girlfriend is a JW and I am pentecostal, 2 days ago she was in her meeting and the presenter said that according to 2 corinthians 6:14 "Be ye no unequally yokes together with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with unrighteousness? KJV. A Jehovah witness shouldn't be married to anyone who isn't a JW.

My point to her was the bible did not say at all that JW shouldn't marry a different christians, it talked about the unrighteous and both of us are righteous persons who have a deep desire for Jehovah.
So my question is, do you think that God will be ok if we get married because according to scripture we are both equally believers.

Comment: According to both Jehovah's Witnesses and Pentecostals, each consider the other to be heretics who worship different gods. This is because Pentecostals believe in the Trinity, and JWs do not. So don't make the mistake of thinking your theological differences are minor, they get right to the very heart of who God is and how we relate to him.

Comment: But, the thing I'm getting at is we both believe in Jehovah. And the reason why I didn't go with the point with the related question like is because they didn't say if that person was a christian as well

Comment: And I meant to add, yes we have different beliefs but according to scripture we are both righteous, so doesn't that count? I really don't want to have to end my relationship

Comment: I'm a JW. I appreciate that you asked this question here, but actually the best people to ask this question to would be the elders in your girlfriend's congregation. They are compassionate people who can help both of you to reason on the Scriptures so that you can make a wise decision that has Jehovah's blessing. Since you have a deep desire for Jehovah, I would encourage you to request a Bible Study with one of Jehovah's Witnesses to learn more, and this will help you to better understand the Bible and your girlfriend.

Comment: Ok thank you for your tip, i will see